# Dojo version compatibility

Tags: dojo

I started working on a web application that currently uses version 0.4.
How would I go about upgrading to the latest version, 1.5?
I don't think it's backward compatible?
Would I make a sub-directory in the "js" dir, call it v1.5, and add new code using a new  tag that references the new version?
Then, over time, refactor the old code to use the new version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *a lot* of changes from 0.4 to the current version (1.5). There used to be some porting guides available on the Dojo site, but they don't seem to be there anymore. It's definitely not backwards compatible.

I haven't played with two versions of Dojo side by side, but if they load together then the method you mentioned is your best bet - any new code using 1.5, and refactor the old code as you go.