# Updating dojo from version 0.4

Tags: dojo

Yes, I know it is 2016...

I have inherited some software at a new employer. When I run dojo.version I find that it is a developer src, object I get is:

```
Object {major: 0, minor: 0, patch: 0, flag: "dev", revision: 6426}
    flag: "dev"
    major: 0
    minor: 0
    patch: 0
    revision: 6426
    toString: ()
    __proto__: Object
```

I believe that this is technically version [0.4](http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/branches/), however I don't know of a way to be certain. Looking through the code, it doesn't look like anything is being done too crazy, however I know dojo's verbage and syntax has changed a lot during migrations.

Is it possible to upgrade to a new version...if not a currently supported version, at least one that was released in the last 10 years, that would have support for newer/ish browsers such as chrome?

if so, Is there any resources to get started in the conversion? I know of [dojo 1.x to 2.0 migration doc](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/releasenotes/migration-2.0.html), but i don't think that is what I am looking for.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4997320/5347034) post from 5 years ago about upgrading to 1.5, answer says trying to run 0.4 and 1.5 in tandem...

Comment: You can probably easily get to 1.6. After that it gets trickier. How big is your code base?

Comment: IIRC, 0.4 to 0.9 was the first big "jump" - didn't 0.4 have `dojo.widget` while 0.9 saw the advent of Dijit?  But yes, the next big jump would be 1.6 to 1.7+.

Comment: Delete/edit

Phillippe - Fairly large...ha...I don't really know how to measure a codebase, but 2mb total of js/jsp that has access to dojo.
@KenFranqueiro - Yes, 0.4 uses dojo.widget.  

I guess my main concern would be 'is it possible', and 'how much has changed'. As well as any resources that are known. Dojos site looks like it only documents back to 1.6, and I have found 0 (read ZERO!) resources on 0.4.

Thanks for the responses!